# Ruby - Subclassing array to make it randomize when flattened

Tags: ruby, arrays, subclass, random

I'm trying to subclass Array in ruby to make it randomize its elements when flatten! is called.  Looking at the source code for Array#flatten (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.src/M002218.html), it looks like it should recursively call flatten! on any array contained within an array.  So, I tried doing something like this:

```
class RandArray < Array
    def randomize!
        self.sort!{rand(3)-1}
    end
    def flatten!
        randomize!
        super
    end
end
```

However, when a normal array contains my RandArray and flatten is called on the normal array, flatten! is never called in my array.  I figure ruby is just calling some other method to flatten the arrays recursively, but I can't figure out what that is.  Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an absolute expert on this but Ruby's Array is written as C code. here is the code for flatten! :

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_flatten_bang(ary)
    VALUE ary;
{
    long i = 0;
    int mod = 0;
    VALUE memo = Qnil;

    while (i<RARRAY(ary)->len) {
        VALUE ary2 = RARRAY(ary)->ptr[i];
        VALUE tmp;

        tmp = rb_check_array_type(ary2);
        if (!NIL_P(tmp)) {
            if (NIL_P(memo)) {
                memo = rb_ary_new();
            }
            i += flatten(ary, i, tmp, memo);
            mod = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (mod == 0) return Qnil;
    return ary;
}
```

As you can see on this line,

```
i += flatten(ary, i, tmp, memo);
```

and here is the implementation for this flatten C function :

```
static long
flatten(ary, idx, ary2, memo)
    VALUE ary;
    long idx;
    VALUE ary2, memo;
{
    VALUE id;
    long i = idx;
    long n, lim = idx + RARRAY(ary2)->len;

    id = rb_obj_id(ary2);
    if (rb_ary_includes(memo, id)) {
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "tried to flatten recursive array");
    }
    rb_ary_push(memo, id);
    rb_ary_splice(ary, idx, 1, ary2);
    while (i < lim) {
    VALUE tmp;

    tmp = rb_check_array_type(rb_ary_elt(ary, i));
    if (!NIL_P(tmp)) {
        n = flatten(ary, i, tmp, memo);
        i += n; lim += n;
    }
    i++;
    }
    rb_ary_pop(memo);

    return lim - idx - 1;   /* returns number of increased items */
}
```

The flatten! code calls directly the C flatten function for any element of the array that validates **rb_check_array_type** it doesn't go back to the ruby code.Instead it accesses the underlying C structure directly bypassing your overloaded implementation.

Not sure how to override this, I think one way could be to reopen Array and rewrite the flatten and flatten! function as pure ruby. 
You would take a performance hit, but then you would be able to overload it as you see fit. And you could always use aliasing to have a "flatten_native" and a "flatten_native!" function on your modified array, to get the perfs back on some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Jean is correct, flatten calls a C function behind the scenes. You could patch the Array class and override the default flatten! method, while still retaining access to the original method.

```
class Array
  alias_method :old_flatten!, :flatten!
  def flatten!
    self.old_flatten!
    self.sort!{rand(3)-1}
  end
end
```

Or you could just add a flatten_with_randomize! to the Array class and use that instead and keep the original flatten! method intact.

Comment: That would randomize all Arrays, not only the RandArrays inside a normal array though...

Comment: That's right. It could be a problem, that's why I'd go with a flatten_with_randomize! method. No need to re-implement flatten! in ruby, and take any performance hit.